# Kubernetes AWS EKS load balancer not provisioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, load-balancing, amazon-eks

Neebie to the world of Kubernetes AWS EKS and would great to get support.

I am trying to deploy a node app. I have the correct IAM policies attached to my IAM role on EKS, I have also setup the correct tags on the private and public subnets.

My Kubernetes yml looks like this.

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: test
          image: test:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          imagePullPolicy: Always
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: test
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 9376
```

The service starts but the external ip just keeps saying pending and no load balancer is provisioned.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot this issue, you can find related failure logs under AWS EKS cluster control plane logs. Please refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/control-plane-logs.html#viewing-control-plane-logs) document from AWS with steps to view AWS EKS cluster control plane logs, also with steps to enable control plane logs.

If you have AWS EKS cluster control plane log available, then you can execute following query in CloudWatch Logs Insights. For information about execution of AWS CloudWatch Logs Insights query, please refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_AnalyzeLogData_RunSampleQuery.html#CWL_AnalyzeLogData_RunQuerySample) document from AWS. After execution of query, check for value of `responseObject.reason` field or you can also expand message to view details.

```
fields @timestamp, @message, requestObject.kind, requestObject.metadata.name,requestObject.spec.type,responseObject.status,responseObject.message,responseObject.reason,requestObject.spec.selector.app
| filter requestObject.spec.type='LoadBalancer' 
| sort @timestamp desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on ALB (Ingress type).

I can view the status (cause of error / success) by command of kubectl as follows. The command helped me to understand error cause which helped me to correct it.

```
kubectl describe ingress <ingress component name> -n <name of namespace>
```

You can get the name of namespace and ingress component name in metadata section from yaml file.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Mnikube

```
minikube tunnel
```

this will help you.

This command can expose the services of type LoadBalancer.

Here is the reference https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/tunnel/ .

Comment: This question was not about minikube and isn't even about local development. Not a relevant answer.