# Failed to create an ALB for my EKS cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I deployed a EKS cluster in AWS. I'd like to create a ALB infront of my cluster. I use below command:

`eksctl create iamserviceaccount --namespace default --name alb-ingress-controller --cluster $componentName --attach-policy-arn $servicePolicyArn --approve --override-existing-serviceaccounts` to create a service account.

below is the ingress I created in k8s:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: es-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: es-entrypoint
              servicePort: 80
```

After apply the config, I got an empty address when run:

```
$ kubectl get ingress/es-ingress
NAME         CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
es-ingress   <none>   *                 80      2d5h
```

I am able to see the service account:

```
$ kubectlaws get serviceaccount alb-ingress-controller
NAME                     SECRETS   AGE
alb-ingress-controller   1         31h
```

what did I do wrong?

Comment: To troubleshoot this issue, you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65354493/kubernetes-aws-eks-load-balancer-not-provisioning/65356571#65356571) method.

Comment: What does the logs of the ingress controller pod say?

Comment: @vishal I have enabled all logs in the cluster. But where can I find the ingress controller log?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao kubectl logs -n <namespace name> <ingress-pod-name>

Answer (score 0):

first of all it would be good to know how did you setup the ALB.
A Service Account is not required, instead you need to have an Ingress Controller. Without that, your Ingress resource is useless. There are a lot of different Ingress Controllers, one of the easiest is the ingress-nginx. But just check this awesome comparison: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/191WWNpjJ2za6-nbG4ZoUMXMpUK8KlCIosvQB0f-oq3k/edit#gid=907731238

So, the easiest way is

- Setup an Ingress Controller
- Configure the Ingress Controller as NodePort with a port like 30080
- Setup your ALB and configure the AWS Target Group to use the NodePort with 30080
- Setup the Ingress resource like above (and you dont need the wildcard in the path)

Now all the traffic from the ALB will redirected to your NodePort (the Ingress Controller). The Ingress ressource is responsible to configure the Nginx configuration inside the Ingress Controller. Thats it!

[The whole traffic flow could look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US8Xi.png)

If this doesnt work

- Check the Ingress Controller logs `kubectl logs --follow --namespace YOURNAMESPACE NAMEOFTHEINGRESSCONTROLLER`
- If you dont get any logs there, just enable the AWS ALB logs and check them

I hope that was helpful, if not, please provide some more detailed information about your infrastructure.