# AWS Cloudwatch Insights how to query using multiple log groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Reading the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/07/cloudwatch-logs-insights-adds-cross-log-group-querying/) seems that is possible in AWS Cloudwatch to run queries with multiple log groups but I can not see any example on how to do it.

I would like to join two log groups using common attributes and select some logs using filter.

Has anyone run into the same problem and found a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can refer [CloudWatch Logs Insights Query Syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html). Some of the examples are 
[examples1](https://reinvent2019.aws-management.tools/mgt306/en/logsinsights.html), [examples2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax-examples.html) , [example3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65356571/14843902)

Comment: thanks for your prompt response but in these examples I can't see how to 'join' different log groups

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about AWS Console, the option to select multiple log groups is a checkbox and you can select over 20 log groups.
[image: AWS CloudWatch Insights Console]

If you refer to the AWS CLI, you can also choose multiple log groups. First create the query (in one or more log groups) (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/start-query.html) and then get the results (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/get-query-results.html)

Example:

Query creation with multiple log groups:

```
aws logs start-query --log-group-names "/aws/apigateway/welcome" "/aws/lambda/Test01" 
--start-time 1598936400000 --end-time 1611464400000 --query-string "fields @timestamp, 
@message"
```

Recover result from created query:

```
aws logs get-query-results --query-id <query_id>
```

[image: AWS CLI CloudWatch Insights]

Comment: thanks, I mean I can select multiple log groups using console but in Logs Insights I would like to 'join' this log groups using same attributes (log_group_alias.common_field) like in SQL not just do an union of different log groups

Comment: @JourneyToJsDude Did you found an answer? I am trying to achieve same thing but with no results. Thank you!

Comment: @LuisaBradusca you found an answer to this?

Comment: @kyw I didn't, I guess it wasn't available at that time. Maybe it is available now (as we are in 07.2022 - also apologies for the late answer, I somehow missed it). As solution we build the query within the application, logged it and then parse it within CloudWatch - the disadvantage is clearly that it is not real-time data.

Answer (score 2):

You can install [Athena Cloudwatch Connector](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/athena-prebuilt-data-connectors-cwlogs.html).
Before that, you will able to query in Athena using each log group like a table.

```
select s.message, c.message, split_part(c.message, '/',3)
from "lambda:athena-cloudwatch-catalog"."/aws/lambda/<LOG_GROUP_1>".all_log_streams c,
"lambda:athena-cloudwatch-catalog"."/aws/lambda/<LOG_GROUP_2>".all_log_streams s
where 
s.message like split_part(c.message, '/',3) and
c.message like '%S3%';
```

Comment: Cool. But we didn't want to pay for another AWS service. Thanks for the tip anyway.