# AWS Cloudwatch Insights: query using multiple log groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Reading the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/07/cloudwatch-logs-insights-adds-cross-log-group-querying/) seems that is possible in AWS Cloudwatch to run queries with multiple log groups but I can not see any example on how to do it.

I would like to join two log groups using common attributes and select some logs using filter.

Has anyone run into the same problem and found a solution? Thanks in advance.

**Working code:**

```
"SOURCE 'abc/application.log' | filter @message not like \"ThrottlingException\"\n| fields logMessage"
```

**Not working code:**

```
"SOURCE 'abc/application.log' 'abc-onebox/application.log' | filter @message not like \"ThrottlingException\"\n| fields logMessage"
                        
"SOURCE IN ['abc/application.log', 'abc-onebox/application.log'] | filter @message not like \"ThrottlingException\"\n| fields logMessage"
```

Comment: Why does your question is a exact duplicate of this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/65905013/13126651 which already has answers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Cloudwatch Insights how to query using multiple log groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65905013/aws-cloudwatch-insights-how-to-query-using-multiple-log-groups)

Comment: Athena Cloudwatch Connector is not an option. My specific query is embedded in a AWS dashboard and i need it to run it from there(therefore the second option in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65905013/aws-cloudwatch-insights-how-to-query-using-multiple-log-groups url does not work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by doing the following. The AWS documentation lives [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/CloudWatch-Dashboard-Body-Structure.html#CloudWatch-Dashboard-Properties-Log-Widget-Object)

```
"SOURCE 'abc/application.log' | SOURCE 'abc-onebox/application.log' | filter @message not like \"ThrottlingException\"\n| fields logMessage"
```